# What is the clojure equivalent for Haskell's <-?

Tags: haskell, clojure, monads

I'm trying to figure out the IO monad and the `<-` syntax which I often see in Haskell code.  I've seen it used with multiple datatypes, including arrays and IO.

What is the equivalent operation in clojure if I were to specify one myself?

Comment: Note that `<-` (and `do`-notation in general) is not an operator at all, but rather syntactic sugar for the `(>>=)` operator (pronounced *bind*). As `(>>=)` is a class method (of the `Monad` class), it has quite different implementations depending on the underlying datatype.

Comment: How is it implemented for IO?

Comment: It doesn't cover <- as such, but maybe this post relating Clojure and Haskell functions could be of some help: http://productivedetour.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/haskell-equivalents-of-some-clojure.html

Comment: A slight clarification: `<-` can't be used with "pretty much anything", only with Monads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`algo.monads`](http://clojure.github.io/algo.monads/#clojure.algo.monads/domonad), we can define an IO monad easily (if unnecesarrily).

In Haskell, the IO monad is `type IO a = World -> (a, World)`. It's handy to think of this as an action - something which takes the world, does *something*, and returns a value and the world.

Using a vector instead of a tuple, this means that, in Clojure, an IO action (a monadic value of the IO monad) looks something like this:

```
(fn [world]
    ; some stuff
    [value world])
```

To do something interesting, we need a couple of actions: `get-char` and `put-char`.

`get-char` is an action which takes in the world, reads a char, and returns that char as its value alongside the world:

```
(defn read-char
  []
  (-> *in* .read char))

(defn get-char
  [world]
  [(read-char) world])
```

`put-char` takes a character and creates an action which, given a world, prints the character and returns some (inconsequential) value:

```
(defn put-char
  [c]
  (fn [world]
    (print c)
    [nil world]))
```

Note that, to make an action happen, we have to supply a world. For instance, `(put-char \a)` will return an action; `((put-char \a) :world)` will invoke that action, printing `a` and returning `[nil :world]`.

Composing these actions is potentially a very messy process. If, for example, you wanted to get a character, then print it, you'd have to call `get-char`, unpack its character and world, create an action for that character with `put-char`, then pass the world to that action.

On the other hand, if we define a monad, we get [`domonad`](http://clojure.github.io/algo.monads/#clojure.algo.monads/domonad) (the equivalent to Haskell's `do`) for free. This syntactic sugar alleviates the unpacking/packing boilerplate. We just need a few functions: `m-result` and `m-bind` (`m-zero` and `m-plus` are also handy, but not necessary).

`m-result` (`return` in Haskell) takes a value and wraps it up as an action:

```
(fn [v]
  (fn [world]
    [v world]))
```

`m-bind` (`>>=` in Haskell) takes an action and a function which takes a regular value to produce an action, "unwraps" the value by invoking the action, and applies the function to it. With the IO monad, that looks like this:

```
(fn [io f]
  (fn [world]
    (let [[v new-world] (io world)]
      ((f v) new-world))))
```

So, using `algo.monads`, we can define `io-m` as follows:

```
(defmonad io-m
  [m-result (fn [v]
              (fn [world]
                [v world]))

   m-bind (fn [io f]
            (fn [world]
              (let [[v new-world] (io world)]
               ((f v) new-world))))])
```

Now that we've got the primitive IO actions and a means of composing them, we can create more interesting ones. Note that Haskell's unpacking operator (`<-`) is implicit and the result is automatically wrapped with `m-result` so we don't use Haskell's `return` statement to terminate the expressions:

```
(declare get-rest-of-line)

(def get-line
  (domonad io-m
    [c get-char
     line (if (= c \newline)
                (m-result "")
                (get-rest-of-line c))]
     line))

 (defn get-rest-of-line
   [c]
   (domonad io-m
     [cs get-line]
     (str c cs)))

 (defn put-line
   [s]
   (if (seq s)
     (domonad io-m
       [_ (put-char (first s))
        _ (put-line (subs s 1))]
       _)
      (put-char \newline)))
```

Finally, we can write a program in terms of these IO actions:

```
(def run-program
  (domonad io-m
    [line get-line
     :let [reversed-line (->> line reverse (apply str))]
     _ (put-line reversed-line)]
    _))

(run-program :world)
```

Answer (score 6):

Do-notation is just sugar for the standard monad operations. For example, if you have something like this:

```
do
  x <- someMonad
  return (someFunction x)
```

That's equivalent to this:

```
someMonad >>= \x -> return (someFunction x)
```

So the equivalent Clojure using one of the many monad libraries might be something like this:

```
(m-bind some-monad (fn [x] (m-result (some-function x))))
```

Comment: I'm looking for a specific example as to how bind may be implemented in clojure using printf and readline for the io monad

Answer (score 3):

I think Chuck has answered your main question, but in case you'd like to investigate the way the monad operations can be implemented in Clojure using [`algo.monads`](https://github.com/clojure/algo.monads) as an example, the following:

```
(domonad state-m
  [_ (set-state "foo")
   x (fetch-state)]
  x)
```

is equivalent (well, almost, see below) to Haskell's

```
do
  _ <- put "foo" -- see below for a comment on this
  x <- get
  return x
```

In `algo.monads` the `<-` disappears, because effectively it is implied on every line.

About the "almost" and the `_` above: `_` actually isn't magic in Clojure and it will be bound to the value returned by `set-state`, but it's idiomatic to use this symbol as the name of locals one doesn't care about. Of course in Haskell it would be more usual simply to write `put "foo"` instead of `_ <- put "foo"`.

Comment: Thank Michal.. would the IO monad be implemented the same way as state?

Comment: @zcaudate, yes, it could be, at some level... Consider reading SPJ's [paper](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fum%2Fpeople%2Fsimonpj%2Fpapers%2Fmarktoberdorf%2Fmark.pdf.gz&ei=bkuiUu6SCsbZ4QTvxYHYBQ&usg=AFQjCNGFue8D4X6wV9nLevHZ-sjjKJc8Eg&sig2=Prah0KQaBIiCrwy_VDF9Dg&bvm=bv.57752919,d.bGE&cad=rjt) on a subject, it can provide some useful insights into IO monad.